# Use multiple SSDs for single geth node

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum, geth

I am setting up a Geth archive node, and it take a lot of space, I have a few SSDs (each 1 tb), I want to configure get in a way that when SSD1 is full it should automatically continue storing new data into SSD2 and so on.
Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Try to set up a zfs pool or raid array. This will combine the drives in a given configuration.
If you don't care about data loss in the event of a disk failure, you can use the 0 configuration, although it is not recomended as one disk will result in a total loss of your data.

Comment: @UsmanSharif, I did not downvote your question. I suspect that it got downvoted because it fits better on Server Fault https://serverfault.com/ (Stackoverflow for IT admins for questions regarding networking, storage etc..).